# Show image album structure on android when using Imagepicker

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to show the image albums structure when using the ImagePicker? For example this version of the ImagePicker https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker.

When I use the ImagePicker like below, all the images are placed in one big list. See screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN8I9.png

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function (result) {                       
        callback(result);
    },
    function (error) {
         callback([]);
    },
    {
        quality: 90, 
        allow_video: false, 
        title : "Select images", 
        message: 'Please select an image' 
    } 
);
```

When I use

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onCameraSuccess, onCameraFail, {
    ...
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    ...
});
```

it allows you to pick an album but you can only select one image from that album at a time. So I am really for combination of these two options.

I've added some example images from WhatsApp to illustrate what I am looking for. If you press and hold an image with WhatsApp (while being inside an album) it allows you select multiple images.

1) WhatsApp. Add picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5xTS.png

2) WhatsApp. Choose gallery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyoLy.png

3) WhatsApp. Overview gallerys

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMbKh.png